# php 8.2 .= not working anymore in new version

Tags: php

I upgraded to PhP 8.2 and now some errors show up.

I construct an select with the code below, but it only works without the .=

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $select_btw .= '<option value="'.$row['ID_btw_soort_inkoop'].'">'.$row['btw_soort_inkoop_omschrijving'].'</option>';
}
```

Why is the .= not working anymore and what is the alternative?

```
Warning: Undefined variable $select_btw in D:\OneDrive\PHP_projecten\Boekhouding\inkoop_invoeren.php
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full error you got

Comment: Whre is defined $selected_btw? or do you mean $row['selected_btw']?

Comment: Define it before you add to it: `$select_btw = '';`